# Setting the encoding

Tags: java, android, encoding

Is there a way to set the enconding for the object requestBuilder. I have this code, which adds paramters to an URL. But when I add some character from the ISO-Latin I dont get the correct enconding:

```
while(kvEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
 KeyValue kv = (KeyValue) kvEnum.nextElement();
 String key = kv.key;
 String value = kv.value;
 System.out.println("######param added - "+ "key: "+key + ", value: "+value);                
 requestBuilder = requestBuilder.appendQueryParameter(key, value);
}
```

Documentation for requestBuilder.appendQueryParameter(key, value); says that encodes, but not which type of coding is using.

Comment: Which kind of object is "requestBuilder"?

Comment: requestBuilder.appendQueryParameter(key, value); just builds query parameters only, when you do actual query you may set the encoding. Are you using HttpURLConnection or something else?

Comment: can you give an example of the characters that are not getting encoded properly. Secondly which package is requestBuilder from? are you referring to the one in GWT?